# Cannot read property 'focus' of null error when extracting component

Tags: reactjs, antd, algolia

I would like to implement Algolia search with Ant Design Autocomplete. But I get `Cannot read property 'focus' of null` error when I try to extract the `SearchInput` component (without extraction, i. e. when I leave it in the same file, it works fine). Here is the working code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { AutoComplete, Input } from 'antd'

const SearchAutocomplete = connectAutoComplete(
  ({ hits, currentRefinement, refine }) => {

    ...

    return (
      <AutoComplete
        options={options}
        onSelect={onSelect}
        onSearch={handleSearch}
        open={open}
      >
        <Input
          value={currentRefinement}
          onChange={e => refine(e.currentTarget.value)}
        />
      </AutoComplete>
    );
  }
);
```

But when I move `Input` to a separate component like this it doesn't work:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { AutoComplete } from 'antd'
import SearchInput from './SearchInput'

const SearchAutocomplete = connectAutoComplete(
  ({ hits, currentRefinement, refine }) => {

    ...

    return (
      <AutoComplete
        options={options}
        onSelect={onSelect}
        onSearch={handleSearch}
        open={open}
      >
        <SearchInput value={currentRefinement} onChange={e => refine(e.currentTarget.value)}/>
      </AutoComplete>
    );
  }
);
```

And the `SearchInput` component itself:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Input } from 'antd'

const SearchInput = props => {
  const { value, onChange} = props;

  return (
    <Input
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  )
}
```

Here is the link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/algolia-autocomplete-fwn3t?file=/src/AutoComplete.js:192-1387) with the extracted component. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `React.forwardRef()` to `SearchInput` solved the issue:

```
const SearchInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { onChange } = props;

  return (
    <Input.Search
      onChange={onChange}
      ref={ref}
    />
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In material-ui AutoComplete component I had a same problem and I have resolved it by passing props to custom render element in the following way

**Error:**

```
<Autocomplete
    renderOption={React.useCallback((props, option, { inputValue }) => {
      return (
          <Box component='li'>
              {option.email}
          </Box>
      )
  })}
/>
```

**Solution:**

```
<Autocomplete
    renderOption={React.useCallback((props, option, { inputValue }) => {
      return (
          <Box component='li' {...props}> // props assigned to Box Component
              {option.email}
          </Box>
      )
  })}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In MUI I had a similar problem and I solved it thanks to [this solution in GitHub.](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/28687#issuecomment-1239576102)

If you are using a TextField as renderInput and have custom additional inputProps, then you need to add  ...params.inputProps, in your inputProps like this:

```
renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Choose a country"
      inputProps={{
        ...params.inputProps, // HERE
        maxLength: 255
      }}
    />
  )}
```